# extract / change location of trendline in xlsx writer

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

Writing to xlsx writer and need to obtain the trendline, say "y=2x + 3", into a csv file, or even another line in excel.

Also would be nice to be able to set the location of where the trendline shows up on the graph.

Example code:

```
g_v_net.add_series({'values':gain,'categories':net,
                   'trendline':{'type':'polynomial','display_equation':True,'order':3})
```

Are there any properties for these tasks?

Comment: `'display_equation':True` should show it in the chart.